# Output lower tri using stargazer

Tags: r, matrix, stargazer

I want to output the lower tri in a matrix and format it to latex for a pretty output.

I have tried:

```
stargazer(overlap_stats1$overlap_prop$iso95[upper.tri(overlap_stats1$overlap_prop$iso95)])
```

but the result is only one line of output.

Comment: Is your model in the list described in `?"stargazer models"` ?

Comment: no. It is a adehabitat overlap iso95 matrix generated according to this: http://tlocoh.r-forge.r-project.org/tips/isopleth_overlap_auto.html

Comment: then stargazer doesn't know how to format it properly. You should try to use another package like `xtable` or `pander`

Comment: I tried pander and that worked fine but i wanted the latex strength of Stargazer

Comment: xtable seems to be a good alternative i see. But. I get too many digits in my output. I tried to use the digits = 2 but that was ignored by xtable. Maybe i should reduce the number of digits in my data before using xtable or the likes??

Comment: you could use `round()` to format digits beforehand. It's hard to help more without a look at the data

Comment: round or signif worked to some degree when applying to the data before using xtable, but in cases with e.g 0.50 the last 0 is ignored. But some progress :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a combination of `signif` and `formatC` like this `a1$overlap_prop$iso95 <- formatC(signif(a1$overlap_prop$iso95, digits = 2), 2, format = "f")` and adding empty spaces in the upper tri inkluding the diagonal made the stargazer output look very nice :-)

Thanks for your help :-)